# Supermicro stuck on boot

Tags: boot, supermicro

I have a server with [X10DRL-i](https://www.supermicro.com/en/products/motherboard/X10DRL-i) running dual [Intel Xeon E5-2630 V3](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/83356/intel-xeon-processor-e5-2630-v3-20m-cache-2-40-ghz.html) and everything works great.
Today I tried to swap both CPUs for [Intel Xeon E5-2680 v4](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/91754/intel-xeon-processor-e5-2680-v4-35m-cache-2-40-ghz.html) but server is unable to boot - it is stuck on "DXE Intel RAS initialization...  91"

Both CPUs work when I try them separately.

I already tried this procedure - https://www.supermicro.com/support/faqs/faq.cfm?faq=18922 and even changed the battery for a new one but no luck.

BIOS is updated to the latest version 3.2.